# What are the squares for in the vertical scrollbar of the visual studio code editor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I see the different coloured squares showing on the vertical scroll bar within VS2012. I have been programming for quite a long time and still have no idea what they do or where I can find a reference as to what each colour is supposed to indicate.

[image: vertical scrollbar with squares]

Comment: Some indicate recent code change some indicate added code some indicate errors and so on

Comment: Is there an online reference with details of the squares. I have tried searching before but turned up nothing.

Comment: See if this question answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953452/what-are-the-little-coloured-bits-on-my-vertical-scroll-bar-in-visual-studio-201

Comment: Are you using ReSharper or another code-cop type util? They usually indicate your code is not formatted/named to the "standard" spec that is configured. I would think you would be able to mouse over them and see a tooltip.

Comment: These ones? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109611/Color-Indicator-for-Code-Changes-Track-Changes-in

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find the answer of all the colors:
[image: Scrollbar dots]

**Details on the scrollbar here:**
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudiouk/archive/2013/08/13/visual-studio-2013-enhanced-scrollbar.aspx