# The colors of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

We recently got our hands on the new Visual Studio 2013 (Professional) and everything is running fine and gives an overall good impression so far.

While working I noticed that right to the scrollbar some parts of that bar are colored differently, exmaples:

- Added code is highlighted yellow
- A blue small horizontal line is indicating where the cursor is currently at

Is there any kind of documentation for this highlighting-feature?

Comment: Have you searched it in web yourself?

Comment: @qxg I did, but was not able to find anything. Also I don't know how the bar is called exactly.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953452/what-are-the-little-coloured-bits-on-my-vertical-scroll-bar-in-visual-studio-201

Comment: search 'visual studio 2013 scrollbar colors' google, all the first 5 links are relative.